# useState hook: wait for state to set before setting load state

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-state

I have a React custom hook for a context in my application. It handles the current user. Within this code, when the auth state is changed, the current user state is set to that authorise user, then loading state set to false to allow the app to render.

However, I'm encountering an error from setCurrentUser method being asynchronous meaning that the loading state is set back to false before the currentUser state is actually updated.

I done a bit of research and see people suggesting using useEffect, however this isn't possible as this state change, as you can see, is already within a useEffect that fires when the component mounts.

See the context hook below:

````
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function useUser() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>
      {!loading && children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}```
````

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you don't call any method inside `useEffect`. `unsubscribe` calls only on unmounting. Maybe you can run 

useEffect(()=>{
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    })
}, [])

Comment: maybe try adding ``loading`` as a dependency in the useEffect